# No module named pkg_resources

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, setuptools, pip

I'm deploying a Django app to a dev server and am hitting this error when I run `pip install -r requirements.txt`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/mydir/virtualenvs/dev/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

`pkg_resources` appears to be distributed with `setuptools`.  Initially I thought this might not be installed to the Python in the virtualenv, so I installed `setuptools 2.6` (same version as Python) to the Python site-packages in the virtualenv with the following command:

```
sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg --install-dir /var/www/mydir/virtualenvs/dev/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

**EDIT:** This only happens inside the virtualenv.  If I open a console outside the virtualenv then `pkg_resources` is present, but I am still getting the same error.

Any ideas as to why `pkg_resources` is not on the path?

Comment: When installing nltk,same problem happens.Good question and helpful answer

Comment: `pip uninstall -y setuptools` and then `pip install setuptools==39.1.0` worked for me on Anaconda on Windows 10.

Comment: @Ryan worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 as well, thank you kind Sir!

Comment: This worked for me on macOS Sonoma 14.2.1: `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools`

Answer (score 818, accepted):

**July 2018 Update**

Most people should now use `pip install setuptools` (possibly with `sudo`).

Some may need to (re)install the `python-setuptools` package via their package manager (`apt-get install`, `yum install`, etc.).

This issue can be highly dependent on your OS and dev environment. See the legacy/other answers below if the above isn't working for you.

**Explanation**

This error message is caused by a missing/broken Python `setuptools` package. Per Matt M.'s comment and [setuptools issue #581](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/581), the bootstrap script referred to below is no longer the recommended installation method.

The bootstrap script instructions will remain below, in case it's still helpful to anyone.

**Legacy Answer**

I encountered the same `ImportError` today while trying to use pip. Somehow the `setuptools` package had been deleted in my Python environment.

To fix the issue, run the setup script for `setuptools`:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python
```

(or if you don't have `wget` installed (e.g. OS X), try

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py | python
```

possibly with `sudo` prepended.)

If you have any version of [`distribute`](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/merge-faq.html), or any `setuptools` below 0.6, you will have to uninstall it first.*

See [Installation Instructions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.9.8#installation-instructions) for further details.

---

* If you already have a working `distribute`, upgrading it to the "compatibility wrapper" that switches you over to `setuptools` is easier. But if things are already broken, don't try that.

Comment: After reading this comment, I realized that I was using pip while at the same time updating my system packages (including several Python distribution packages) in the background. Turned out to be a bad idea...

Comment: Piping curl to a local command always scares me, but this works great. :) I had run `sudo python` though YMMV.

Comment: @NikReiman I ran bin/python so it would install in my virtualenv. Worked great!

Comment: Under Cygwin I had to install the **python-setuptools** package.  This got **easy_install** working again, which had suffered the same problem.  Then I used `easy_install pip` to get pip working again.  My problem arose from Cygwin upgrading Python from 2.6 to 2.7 behind my back while installing something unrelated.

Comment: +1 saved me a re-install.  I'd followed the updated `brew doctor` advice to empty out `/usr/local/share/python/` and unthinkingly extended this to deleting `easy_install`. This curl one liner fixed it all.

Comment: This was the best answer last year… but as of mid-2013, `distribute` is obsolete, and `setuptools` is its successor. I'll edit the answer to update it, but I'm not sure that's the best way to handle it, so someone may revert the edit, in which case: Go [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.9.8#installation-instructions).

Comment: This URL didn't work for me but this one did: http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py

Comment: @Cerin: It would be more helpful for everybody if you say what happened when you tried. And did you use `sudo`, as @Nik noted above?

Comment: I was getting this error when running `xattr` on mac. That uses the system python (and `python` for me was one I installed). So for me the command was `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py | sudo /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`

Comment: Thanks, @StevePitchers, `sudo yum reinstall python-setuptools` solved the issue for me (without needing to pipe curl). Hit the problem updating via pip in the first place.

Comment: It looks like that bitbucket repo has been moved to github. The new command would be wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/setuptools/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | python

Comment: Awesome thanks! PS: in my case, the problem is in `pip3`, so I had to run with `python3`.

Comment: even with `sudo` i get the following error: `error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/<my_name>/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/easy-install.pth'
`

Comment: [This method is deprecated](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/581).

Comment: Distribute link is broken http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/merge-faq.html

Comment: ez_setup.py is deprecated

Comment: `ez_setup.py is deprecated and when using it setuptools will be pinned to 33.1.1 since it's the last version that supports setuptools self upgrade/installation, check https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/581 for more info; use pip to install setuptools` - part of the output from the command in this answer

Comment: after installing setuptools, this problem has been resolved.

Comment: `apt-get install --reinstall python-setuptools ` works for me, an ubuntu 14.04 server.

Comment: I had a similar issue expect that the import caused the following error `AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'`, I solved it using `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall setuptools`.

Comment: on MacOS 10.15 I had to run:
`pip3 install --upgrade setuptools --user`

Comment: It's time for another update 2021 ;-) Not one of the answers or comments mentions Arch Linux. I've broken my system's pip/setuptools by trying to install locust (`pip install locust`) inside a venv and running into issues with pkg_resources after that. What fixed my pip was `python3 -m ensurepip --default-pip`. After that I was able to update pip via `python -m ensurepip --upgrade`. UP TO DATE INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS for PIP: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

Comment: For py3 crowd, sudo apt install --reinstall python3-pkg-resources python3-setuptools

Comment: The installation of Node.js caused `pkg_resources` missing in my case. It broke my python setup by being all "I sit on your couch and spit crumbs all over it, because 'dude, trust me you need that' ".

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'` is happenning with the wget command :(

Comment: This answer needs a 2023 update. The relevant library is removed from Python 3.12 and so a lot more people will hit this answer and not know why. The reason is that the latest version of python does not install this by default anymore and you're expected to switch to import_lib

Comment: +1 helped me so solves my issue. Was using eth_accounts in virtualenv python 3.12. Added setuptools to requirements.txt and install then all started to working.

Answer (score 150):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-pkg-resources
```

fixed it for me in Debian. Seems like uninstalling some .deb packages (twisted set in my case) has broken the path python uses to find packages

Comment: I'm using Python 3 so I had to run sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-pkg-resources and that fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: did not help with yapf i guess, something to do with python3/python2

Answer (score 79):

I have seen this error while trying to install rhodecode to a virtualenv on ubuntu 13.10. For me the solution was to run

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --upgrade distribute
```

before I run easy_install rhodecode.

Comment: `pip install --upgrade setuptools` alone did the trick for me.

Comment: i needed `pip install --upgrade setuptools --user`

Comment: I can't run `pip install --upgrade setuptools` due to the same error: `No module named pkg_resources`

Comment: `pip install --upgrade distribute` did the job when using Python 3's venv module. Python 2's virtualenv supported `--distribute` flag, but one has to install `distribute` on environments created by `venv`.

Comment: I was using pipenv for my Django project. `pipenv install setuptools` solved the issue I was facing. Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

It also happened to me. I think the problem will happen if the requirements.txt contains a "distribute" entry while the virtualenv uses setuptools. Pip will try to patch setuptools to make room for distribute, but unfortunately it will fail half way.

The easy solution is delete your current virtualenv then make a new virtualenv with --distribute argument.

An example if using virtualenvwrapper:

```
$ deactivate
$ rmvirtualenv yourenv
$ mkvirtualenv yourenv --distribute
$ workon yourenv
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: this helped me when none of the other solutions did (using Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: For environments created by Python 3's venv module, running `pip install -U distribute` after activating the environment will do the job.

Answer (score 20):

After trying several of these answers, then reaching out to a colleague, what worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 was:

```
pip install --force-reinstall -U setuptools
pip install --force-reinstall -U pip
```

In my case, it was only an old version of pillow 3.1.1 that was having trouble (pillow 4.x worked fine), and that's now resolved!

Answer (score 18):

In CentOS 6 installing the package python-setuptools fixed it.

```
yum install python-setuptools
```

Comment: This works in Debian if when you replace "yum"  with "sudo apt-get".  Also:  `sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools`

Comment: This is the one that did it for me.

Comment: I had this problem on CentOS 7, and python-setuptools was already installed, but `sudo yum reinstall python-setuptools` fixed it.

Comment: Reported the bug to CentOS.org    https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=14042

Answer (score 14):

I had this error earlier and the highest rated answer gave me an error trying to download the `ez_setup.py` file. I found another source so you can run the command:

```
curl http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py | python
```

I found that I also had to use `sudo` to get it working, so you may need to run:

```
sudo curl http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py | sudo python
```

I've also created another location that the script can be downloaded from:

https://gist.github.com/ajtrichards/42e73562a89edb1039f3

Comment: The "curl" command would not need sudo, so it could be: `curl http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py | sudo python`

Comment: this answer saved me with "| sudo python" addition, because "| python" alone did not work! Thanks

Answer (score 11):

A lot of answers are recommending the following but if you read through the source of that script, you'll realise it's deprecated.

```sh
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python
```

If your pip is also broken, this won't work either.

```sh
pip install setuptools
```

I found I had to run the command from [Ensure pip, setuptools, and wheel are up to date](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-pip-setuptools-and-wheel-are-up-to-date), to get pip working again.

```sh
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

Comment: didn't worked for me on Arch based Manjaro Linux

Answer (score 8):

Needed a little bit more sudo. Then used easy_install to install pip. Works.

```
sudo wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python
sudo easy_install pip
```

Comment: `sudo` should not be required in a virtualenv

Comment: True, I just had the same issue without a virtualenv.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed the error with virtualenv by doing this:

Copied pkg_resources.py from

`/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools`

to

`/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`

This may be a cheap workaround, but it worked for me.

.

If setup tools doesn't exist, you can try installing system-site-packages by typing `virtualenv --system-site-packages /DESTINATION DIRECTORY`, changing the last part to be the directory you want to install to. `pkg_rousources.py` will be under that directory in lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: yes in some projects, this solutions is best (for me)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the command
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-pkg-resources`
if you are using python3 , this was the case with me.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem after installing the latest Python version `3.10.4`.
Somehow, the `setuptools` package and pip were deleted.

I used the following command to resolve the issue :
in [Windows]

```
py -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

Answer (score 4):

the simple resoluition is that you can use conda to upgrade setuptools or entire enviroment. (Specially for windows user.)

```
conda upgrade -c anaconda setuptools
```

if the setuptools is removed, you need to install setuptools again.

```
conda install -c anaconda setuptools
```

if these all methodes doesn't work, you can upgrade conda environement. But I do not recommend that you need to reinstall and uninstall some packages because after that it will exacerbate the situation.

Answer (score 3):

For me, this error was being caused because I had a subdirectory called "site"!  I don't know if this is a pip bug or not, but I started with:

/some/dir/requirements.txt
/some/dir/site/

pip install -r requirements.txt wouldn't work, giving me the above error!

renaming the subfolder from "site" to "src" fixed the problem!  Maybe pip is looking for "site-packages"?  Crazy.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it turned out to be a permissions problem on `site-packages`. Since it's only my dev environment, I raised the permissions and everything is working again:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /path/to/my/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I had activated my virtualenv as a different user than the one who created it. It seems to be a permission problem. I discovered this when I tried the answer by @cwc and saw this in the output:

```
Installing easy_install script to /path/env/bin
error: /path/env/bin/easy_install: Permission denied
```

Switching back to the user that created the virtualenv, then running the original `pip install` command went without problems. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem today as well. I only got the problem inside the virtual env.

The solution for me was deactivating the virtual env, deleting and then uninstalling virtualenv with pip and reinstalling it. After that I created a new virtual env for my project, then pip worked fine both inside the virtual environment as in the normal environment.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like they have moved away from bitbucket and are now on github (https://github.com/pypa/setuptools)

Command to run is:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python
```

Comment: File "/python/Python-3.5.1/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 162, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/python/Python-3.5.1/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 465, in open
 
  File "/python/Python-3.5.1/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 488, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "/python/Python-3.5.1/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/python/Python-3.5.1/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 1310, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>

Answer (score 2):

If you are encountering this issue with an application installed via [conda](https://conda.io/docs/), the solution (as stated in [this bug report)](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/239) is simply to install setup-tools with:

```
conda install setuptools
```

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, with python 3.7, this worked for me:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools --user
```

`--user` installs packages in your home directory, which doesn't require admin privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you're missing setuptools. Some virtualenv versions use distribute instead of setuptools by default. Use the `--setuptools` option when creating the virtualenv or set the `VIRTUALENV_SETUPTOOLS=1` in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

None of the posted answers worked for me, so I reinstalled pip and it worked!

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essential 

sudo easy_install pip 

pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

(reference: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/02/how-install-pip-ubuntu/)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources'

Comment: owner-Dimension-3000 owner # sudo easy_install pip 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
owner-Dimension-3000 owner # pip install --upgrade setuptools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
owner-Dimension-3000 owner #

Comment: did you first remove installed pip version?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had 2 python versions installed initially and later I had deleted the older one. So while creating the virtual environment

```
virtualenv venv
```

was referring to the uninstalled python

What worked for me

```
python3 -m virtualenv venv
```

Same is true when you are trying to use pip.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error in a poetry environment.

Steps I took to resolve it:

1. Add setuptools as a dev dependency with

```
poetry add --dev setuptools
```

2. Install setuptools in the poetry env using

```
poetry run pip install setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this answer when I was trying to follow [this guide for OSX](http://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/). What worked for me was, after running `python get-pip`, I had to ALSO `easy_install pip`. That fixed the issue of not being able to run pip at all. I *did* have a bunch of old macport stuff installed. That may have conflicted.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, I installed pip downloaded from [www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) then encontered this problem.

So I should have installed setuptools(easy_install) first.

Answer (score 0):

just reinstall your `setuptools` by :

```
$ sudo wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11.tar.gz#md5=7df2a529a074f613b509fb44feefefe74e
$ tar -zxvf setuptools-0.6c11.tar.gz
$ cd setuptools-0.6c11/
$ sudo python setup.py build
$ sudo python setup.py install
$ sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

then everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use CentOS 6.7, and my python was just upgrade from 2.6.6 to 2.7.11, after tried so many different answer, finally the following one does the job:

```
sudo yum install python-devel
```

Hope help someone in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem after updating my Ubuntu build.  It seems to have gone through and removed set up tools in all of my virtual environments.

To remedy this I reinstalled the virtual environment back into the target directory.  This cleaned up missing setup tools and got things running again.

e.g.:

```
~/RepoDir/TestProject$ virtualenv TestEnvironmentDir
```

Answer (score 0):

For me a good fix was to use `--no-download` option to virtualenv (`VIRTUALENV_NO_DOWNLOAD=1 tox` for tox.)

Answer (score 0):

On Opensuse 42.1 the following fixed this issue:

```
zypper in python-Pygments
```

Answer (score 0):

**ImportError: No module named pkg_resources:** the solution is to reinstall python pip using the following  Command are under.

**Step: 1** Login in root user.

```
sudo su root
```

**Step: 2** Uninstall python-pip package if existing.

```
apt-get purge -y python-pip
```

**Step: 3** Download files using wget command(File download in `pwd` )

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

**Step: 4** Run python file.

```
python ./get-pip.py
```

**Step: 5** Finaly exicute installation  command.

```
apt-get install python-pip
```

**Note:** User must be root.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced that error in my Google App Engine environment. And `pip install -t lib setuptools` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem when I used easy-install to install pip for python 2.7.14. For me the solution was (might not be the best, but worked for me, and this is probably the simplest) that the folder that contained the `easy-install.py` also contained a folder `pkg_resources`, and i have copy-pasted this folder into the same folder where my `pip-script.py` script was (`python27\Scripts`).
Since then, I found it in the `python27\Lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg\pip\_vendor` folder as well, it might be a better solution to modify the `pip-script.py` file to import this.

Answer (score 0):

`yum -y install python-setuptools`

i configure the Ceph there is a problem execute command `"$ ceph-deploy new node1"`,
and I execute the command `"$ yum -y install python-setuptools"`,
then the problem is gone.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I caused this error (or very similar) by removing the "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/" directory from my machine thinking it was a local cache.  Only easy_install stopped working (pip was fine).

None of the items listed here helped me but I was able to recover by downloading the latest from https://www.python.org/downloads/ and installing it.  Luckily I was not on latest, as I believe otherwise I would have had to reinstall.

I suspect (but not 100% sure) I also needed to open a new terminal (or new tab in terminal) to have it work.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I did:

```
pip install -U poetry
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Python 3, you should use pip3 instead of pip. The command looks like `$ pip3 install requirements.txt`