# distribute a usable python program to a python which doesn't have Distribute installed?

Tags: python, windows, software-distribution, distribute

How to distribute a usable python program to a python which doesn't have Distribute installed?

I've created a Windows Binary installer using `python setup.py bdist_wininst`. The setup.py contains a console script entry point, so that a Windows .exe file is created and placed in `%python%\Scripts` on the destination machine, as per [Automatic Script Creation](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation).

However running the installed script on a machine with a virgin python install yields:

```
D:\Py3.2.5> scripts\foo.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Py3.2.5\scripts\foo-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

[No module named pkg_resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources) tells me this error is because [Distribute](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/index.html) is not installed.

How do I get my installer to include Distribute so I don't have to tell our users *"before you install our program you have to go install this other program"*?

Comment: why dont you just use py-installer or py2exe that bundles all your dependencies into a runnable exe

Comment: @joran, I'm going to do that too, as a future stage, but I don't want to force people to install a duplicate python if they already have one, especially since some want 3.x and others 2.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, finally [found something](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#using-setuptools-without-bundling-it):

> Your users might not have setuptools installed on their machines, or
>   even if they do, it might not be the right version. Fixing this is
>   easy; just download `distribute_setup.py`, and put it in the same
>   directory as your setup.py script. (Be sure to add it to your revision
>   control system, too.) Then add these two lines to the very top of your
>   setup script, before the script imports anything from setuptools:
>
> ```
> import distribute_setup
> distribute_setup.use_setuptools()
> ```
>
> That’s it. The distribute_setup module will automatically download a
>   matching version of setuptools from PyPI, if it isn’t present on the
>   target system. Whenever you install an updated version of setuptools,
>   you should also update your projects’ distribute_setup.py files, so
>   that a matching version gets installed on the target machine(s).