# Python: ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Tags: python, pip, pelican

In order to run Pelican, I installed python2.7 and modified first line of file /usr/bin/pelican-quickstart

from:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

when I type pelican-quickstart an error occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pelican-quickstart", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

I found "pkg_resources" is in this directory:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-package/
```

I'm wondering if I have to install some packages after python2.7 is installed?
or, how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources

run setup script for `setuptools`

Comment: In my case, I use `sudo yum install python-devel` fixed the error.

Answer (score 6):

The problem must be an issue with your setup tools, try the following:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --upgrade distribute
```

If this solution doesn't work, you can check the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources)

Comment: Both these commands give me the same error as the original question ("ImportError: No module named pkg_resources)

Comment: Why was this answer accepted?

Comment: @Cerin I guess because of the linked answer which works

Comment: I ran into this issue when trying to use virtualenvwrapper on python2.7.3. Using this fix worked for me. Thank you Leonardo!

Comment: I had the same issue as JonathanHartley and then read WillCharlton's comment and followed the link. The Link lead me to my answer.

Comment: To fix the issue, run the setup script for setuptools:

wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python
(or if you don't have wget installed (e.g. OS X), try

curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py | python
possibly with sudo prepended.)

If you have any version of distribute, or any setuptools below 0.6, you will have to uninstall it first.*

Answer (score -3):

You said

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-package/
```

but should be

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
```