# ImportError: No module named pkg_resources after I upgrade python from 2.6.6 to 2.7.3

Tags: python

When I run `pip install xxx` or `easy_install xxx`, I met this problem after upgrading Python from 2.6.6 to 2.7.3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Could someone give me some advice ?

Comment: This might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources

Answer (score 0):

first try to run python26 or python27 to see what happening.

check if setting PYTHONPATH in shell.
unset it!

or set it
`PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`