# ImportError: No module named pkg_resources when running pip on Amazon EC2

Tags: python, django, node.js, amazon-ec2, apt

I'm trying to set up an EC2 instance with django but I'm having issues installing anything.  I ran `sudo apt-get update` and `upgrade -y`. But when I try to run pip  which it claims is installed I get this:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-62-51:/home$ pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

When I try `sudo apt-get upgrade -y` I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-virtual linux-image-virtual linux-virtual
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python-pip (1.0-1build1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 36, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
dpkg: error processing python-pip (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-twisted-names (11.1.0-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 36, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
dpkg: error processing python-twisted-names (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pip
 python-twisted-names
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I actually get this error anything I try to use apt-get for anything.

Also anytime I try to actually use pip I get this:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-62-51:/home$ sudo pip install virtualenv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

When I try to use apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/nodejs (since `sudo apt-get install nodejs` doesn't work) I get:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-62-51:/home$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/nodejs
  File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 37
    print _("The %s named '%s' has no PPA named '%s'"
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I had it work before, but I was having the same problems with pip and such, I tried a fresh instance using Ubuntu Server 12 rather than 14, but I'm having same problems.  Although on 14 I couldnt get nginx to install and on 12 I could.  I was able to install ruby, as well as ruby gems like sass/scss.  I got node installed without the new repo.  npm won't install via apt-get though, same error as before.  Why is this happening?  I can't even get virtualenv installed, I can't use this for development as it doesn't even have all the items I need for the production product.  Is ubuntu 12 the problem (although 14 had issues too).  Should I switch to another AMI?

Any idea why things aren't working right?

Thanks

EDIT:  I get the same error if i try to remove pip with apt.

Comment: Do you do anything funny like upgrading Python on the server or install any libraries using `sudo pip`? On fresh EC2 Ubuntu install this definitely is not happening, so maybe we have different concept of fresh or different base image.

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources ?

Comment: I tried, still didn't work

Comment: And yes, it was a fresh instance, I didn't do anything but install ruby, gunicorn, and nginx

Comment: I managed to get it working by just starting a new instance.  Still not what was the actual problem.  I tried a premade AMI and had the same issues, and then tried another instance from scratch and it began to work.  Confusing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Switching to a fresh EC2 instance fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use 'sudo pip install xxx',it fixed my problem.