# Remote server setup: nuclide-start-server command doesn't work

Tags: python, npm, atom-editor, traceback, nuclide-editor

I'm not able to connect remotely using atom's new nuclide package. I ran `npm install -g nuclide-server` and followed the the trouble shooting instructions from the nuclide docs http://nuclide.io/docs/remote/ but I keep getting errors. When I run `nuclide-start-server` on my server, I end up this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "scripts/nuclide_server_manager.py", line 25, in <module>
    from nuclide_server import LOG_FILE
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nuclide-server/scripts/nuclide_server.py", line 18, in <module>
import utils File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nuclide server/scripts/utils.py", line 16, in <module> from pkg_resources import resource_string
```

In atom when I try to connect, I get this error which is pretty much summarized above:

```
Bad stdout from remote server: SYNSYN SYNSYN

stderr:bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Invalid argument bash:no job control in this shell Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "scripts/nuclide_server_manager.py", line 25, in from nuclide_server import LOG_FILE File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nuclide-server/scripts/nuclide_server.py", line 18, in import utils 
File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nuclide-server/scripts/utils.py", line 16, in from pkg_resources import resource_string ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you open a GitHub Issue for this? https://github.com/facebook/nuclide The team more closely monitors GitHub Issues than StackOverflow at the moment.

Comment: @ssorallen Yeah I added it here: https://github.com/facebook/nuclide/issues/130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to this problem from this post --> [No module named pkg_resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources):

I encountered the same ImportError today while trying to use pip. Somehow the setuptools package had been deleted in my Python environment.

To fix the issue, run the setup script for setuptools:

`wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | python`

If you have any version of distribute, or any setuptools below 0.6, you will have to uninstall it first.*

See [Installation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.9.8#installation-instructions) Instructions for further details.

FYI: You might need to put a sudo after the pipe. I did. Or put the entire command in quotes, with sudo in the beginning.