# ImportError: No module named pkg_resources on installing matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, centos, installation, pip

This is on CentOs 6.6. I am trying to set up a scientific python environment. I want to avoid Anaconda. When trying to install matplotlib, I get "ImportError: No module named pkg_resources". Full install history:

```
sudo yum install gcc-c++.x86_64
sudo yum install gcc
sudo yum install atlas atlas-devel lapack-devel blas-devel
sudo yum install python-devel
sudo pip install numpy
sudo pip install scipy
sudo pip install pandas
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

At the last step, I get the message

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available,
and can't be installed while this script is running. Please
install a more recent version first, using
'easy_install -U distribute'.
```

Then I do

```
sudo pip install --upgrade distribute
```

which installs `distribute-0.7.3`, `setuptools-18.0.1`. Then:

```
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

which results in:

```
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Any ideas?

#### Update

After the above steps, `setuptools` and `pip` are broken in this installation. From a python shell, doing `help()` followed by `modules` does not list `setuptools`. A search in the filesystem for `setuptools` directories reveals:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-18.0.1.dist-info/
```

while the `setuptools.pth` file in `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/` contains a pointer to the non-existent `./setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info`.

At the same time, there is a directory

```
/usr/share/doc/python-setuptools-0.6.10/
```

After all this, pip no longer works.

Comment: `distribute` is dead. Does removing distribute and installing/upgrading `setuptools` and `pip` solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources ?

Comment: @cel Trying to uninstall `distribute` resulted in the same error. Looking into it..

Comment: @nikosd, I usually recommend anaconda, because it makes things so simple. If you do not want to use anaconda, I would at least use a `virtualenv`. This issue could be caused by a fight between your package manager and pip - `using sudo` for `pip` is in most cases a bad sign :)

Comment: @cel, agreed, eventually everything will be in a `virtualenv` due to `Flask`. I'll try that.

Comment: @juanmajmjr The accepted answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources did not work either. Trying to remove `distribute` as described here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.9.8#installation-instructions

Answer (score 4):

@pavan  they said CentOS, so apt is unlikely to help them.

They could, though, do :

```
yum remove python-setuptools

yum install python-setuptools
```

(my also need to reinstall pip:  yum install python-pip )

And that might fix the problem.

Comment: The project this was meant for has been happily decommissioned, so I do not have access to that CentOS machine any more. I will try it next time such an approach is needed, in the meantime someone else might be able to check if reinstalling python-setuptools fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for OS supporting apt-get (Ubuntu etc)

sudo apt-get install python-pkg-resources python-setuptools --reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Try install python-pip (and dependencies):

```
yum install python-pip
```

This solved my problem (Centos release 6.8).