# Why does pip stop working on debian/ubuntu when updated

Tags: python, debian, pip, ubuntu-12.04, debian-based

I started a few Debian vagrant boxes. After executing `pip install --upgrade pip`, the pip command stopped working.

```
root@debian6010-db1:/vagrant# pip install Jinja2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Somehow I fixed the issue on one of my machines. But the issue persists on the rest. I had the same problem on Ubuntu vagrant boxes. pip broke.

Comment: Have you considered the configuration of Python on the environment? Also are you using Python 2 or 3? It could be a number of reasons.

Comment: did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Comment: I tried `wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | python`. And that did fix pip. But as soon as I run `pip install --upgrade pip` again, I get the following error `root@ubuntu-lb:/home/vagrant# pip install Jinja2
bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory`. And that is frustrating. I should be able to update pip without breaking it.

Answer (score -2):

Purging and reinstalling might be your best option

sudo apt-get purge python-pip

Comment: What about the reinstall? Purging isn't helpful in itself

Comment: I did try reinstalling. That did not fix the problem.