# Any reason setup.py install_requires should include setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I've noticed some python projects include `setuptools` in the list of required modules.  My code installs and executes fine without it.

I may be mistaken, but I think the purpose of the `install_requires` list is to specify the modules needed for execution after installation, not during installation.

Is there some special use-case where it makes sense to install `setuptools`?

```
install_requires=[
    'setuptools',
    'requests',
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project makes use of `pkg_resources`, for example to load resources from [entry points](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#entry-points), it's run-time dependent on `setuptools` (which includes the `pkg_resources` package).

Since Django's `setup.py` does not include `setuptools` as a requirement but does make use of `pkg_resouces`, this [can lead to confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources).

Comment: Thank you for answering.  If if understand correctly, there are some situations where setuptools is available during installation, but not available in the execution environment, and therefore needs to be installed into the execution environment.

Comment: If a distribution is installed from a [wheel](https://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or an egg, setuptools is not even needed during installation. But of course, if setuptools is uninstalled after installation of the package depending on it, `install_requires` will not be able to do anything about that.