# ImportError: No module named pkg_resources when I am trying to use py2exe

Tags: python, pandas, ggplot2, py2exe

I have been trying to make .exe application from my python scripts using py2exe. However, I am seeing the following error message when I run my exe file.

[Error message when I run my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GigGB.png)

Can someone tell me whats wrong, since my python script runs smoothly in spyder IDE, but makes me hit my head on the wall when I try to run my exe application:(

Few ideas which I have thought about so far: 
My matplotlib backends are not configured properly since I am just printing my ggplot figures.

Comment: Post the error message here not in an image. When the image goes down your question becomes useless for this website and future users.

Comment: have you looked at this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources