# Mac reinstall Python

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

I tried to use the Coursera course downloader from [here](https://github.com/coursera-dl/coursera-dl) and it worked for few courses but not all. They have recommended to use Python3.X. So I uninstalled Anaconda (version 2) from my Mac and installed Python3.5.1 from Python's website but still the course downloaders did not work as it was using default Python 2.7.

So I deleted Python from `/usr/local/lib` and now nothing is working. When I do `which python` it shows ``usr/local/bin/python`and both`python`and`python3` runs.

But when I do `pip install coursera` it throws error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

And when I do `sudo easy_install pip`, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Answer (score 0):

try Homebrew http://brew.sh/

```
brew install python3

curl bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Mac should have Python 2 and Python 3 installed by default. in the terminal "python" will launch Python2, "python3" will launch Python3. With Anaconda you could have just kept the Python 2 version and created an environment for Python 3, http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#managing-environments.

This is the solution you will most likely need, [No module named pkg_resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources). Setuptools is causing the issue and you will need to wget ez_setup.py. Reinstalling Anaconda will save you a lot of time and pain.