# Yandex-tank not working

Tags: load-testing, yandex, yandex-tank

Good day.

When I trying to run yandex-tank test, i recieve next text in console:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yandex-tank", line 5, in 
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Yandex-tank installed on vagrant VM Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

**load.ini-file**

```
[phantom]
address=http://*host_mane*.com/articles/get_article
rps_schedule=line(1,100,1m)
ammo_type=phantom
```

**Request-file**

```
238
POST http://*host_name*.com/articles/get_article HTTP/1.1
Host: *host_name*.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 88

{
    "url": "blah-blah-blah.com"
}
```

Starting tank in console with **yandex-tank post.txt**

What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

it seems as a problem with broken setuptools installation. Have you checked [No module named pkg_resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources)?