# How to install numpy for python 2.7.9

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have two versions of python- 2.7.6 & 2.7.9 and numpy is installed for python 2.7.6 . I can't understand how to install numpy for python 2.7.9.

When I use `pip2 install --upgrade numpy`, it installs and updates for python 2.7.6.

How do I install numpy particularly for python 2.7.9?

*****edit*****

I am trying to find the location of python 2.7.9.

If i type `python` or `python2`, I am using python 2.7.9. `which -a python` gives me two paths, `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/local/bin/python` and when I used the first path, it gives me this output-
`Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...`

If I used the second path, i get this output-
`/usr/local/bin/python: No module named pip`

`which -a pip` command gives `/usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip`

`which -a easy_install` gives `/usr/local/bin/easy_install /usr/bin/easy_install`

`which -a python` gives `/usr/local/bin/python /usr/bin/python`

*****edit2*****

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04lts.

`/usr/local/bin/pip --version` gives `pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`.

`/usr/bin/pip --version` gives `pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`

`/usr/local/bin/easy_install --version` gives `setuptools 32.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (Python 2.7)`

`/usr/bin/easy_install --version` gives `setuptools 3.3`

`/usr/local/bin/python --version` gives `Python 2.7.9`

`/usr/bin/python --version` gives `Python 2.7.6`

*****edit3*****

`sudo /usr/local/bin/easy_install pip` gives following output-

```
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 1.5.4
Adding pip 1.5.4 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

*****edit4*****

```
sys.path = [
'/home/kevmepls',
'/home/kevmepls/Documents/DeepLearning-Caffe/caffe/python',
'/usr/local/lib/python27.zip',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/home/kevmepls/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/kevmepls/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/kevmepls/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Comment: How about uninstall 2.7.6, including `numpy`, then install a fresh `numpy` on 2.7.9. Or even completely purge your system of all python installations and then do this. Seems like a much cleaner option.

Comment: I think that the canonical answer to this question is that it's better that you start using virtual environments (If you're using `numpy`, anaconda is nice).  Barring that, presumably there is a `pip` specific to each python installation.  You need to find the `pip` that goes with the 2.7.9 installation and use that one.

Comment: I thought it was a bad idea to remove any python version as I may accidentally remove some system dependencies?

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
/path/to/python279 -m pip install --user numpy
```

If you are seeing the error `No module named pip`, then first install pip as described below:

1. Download this file: [`get_pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
2. Execute `sudo /path/to/python279 get_pip.py`
3. Try again the `/path/to/python279 -m pip install --user numpy`

Comment: Hi wim, sorry for the late reply. How do I exactly find the location of python 2.7.9? I can only find for python 2.7.6 which is in usr/local/lib .

Comment: Well, how do you normally run python 2.7.9?  Try checking the output of `which -a python`.

Comment: I edited the question to show the output of `which -a python`.

Comment: OK.  You'll have to first install pip using `easy_install`.

Comment: I actually have pip installed already and I can see the file in `usr/local/bin` .

Comment: You have it installed but it's not for the correct interpreter.  Use the command `which pip`, edit the file that points at, and modify the first line (which starts with `#!` and then a path to a python interpreter) so that it's using the right interpreter.

Comment: I changed the path to both #!/usr/bin/python2.7 and #!/usr/bin/python2 but i get this output- Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages Cleaning up.... So it is still linking with python 2.7.6 instead of python 2.7.9.

Comment: I'm still having a problem with installing numpy for python 2.7.9. It always installs to my python 2.7.6 instead.

Comment: Try this command:  `/usr/local/bin/python -m easy_install pip`.  Then repeat the command in my answer.  If that doesn't work, edit your question and add more details: your os/platform, the output of `which -a easy_install`, `which -a pip` and `which -a python`.

Comment: Even though the file easy_install is there, the command `/usr/local/bin/python -m easy_install pip`  gives me this error `/usr/local/bin/python: No module named easy_install`. Also I've edited the question.

Comment: For each of the 6 executables listed, please add the details of the output of `executable -- version`.  I also asked what os/platform you're using.

Comment: I've edited the question. Btw thanks wim for helping out with my problem patiently.

Comment: Looks like the distribution in local is the right one.  So try this:  `/usr/local/bin/easy_install pip` and then `/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --user numpy`

Comment: pip seems to be installed but when I enter `/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --user numpy`, i get this output - `/usr/local/bin/python: No module named pip`                                                                                                                   I've edited the question to show the output of `/usr/local/bin/easy_install pip`

Comment: You mentioned in [an earlier comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41448804/how-to-install-numpy-for-python-2-7-9/41448929#comment70288724_41448929) that you tried modifying the `#!` line, but you didn't modify it to the correct interpreter.  Try editing the file at `/usr/local/bin/pip` so that it's using `#!/usr/local/bin/python` and then doing `/usr/local/bin/pip install --user numpy`.  If that still doesn't work, please add the output of the following command:  `/usr/local/bin/python -m site`.  We will get there eventually....!

Comment: After doing the above edits, `/usr/local/bin/pip install --user numpy` gives me this error - `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`                                                           . Do you have any idea how to solve this? See the question edit for output of `/usr/local/bin/python -m site`

Comment: Somehow `setuptools` package has been deleted in your environment.  Please try the answer shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7446187/674039) and see if it resolves that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with your path variables.  Currently, I believe your path variable points to your installation of Python 2.7.6.  Check your path variable for python, and hopefully changing it to the correct installation fixes your issue.