# No module named 'pkg_resources'

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I tried to upgrade tensorflow with `pip install tensorflow --upgrade`. 
During the uninstallation of the old version of `setuptools` some error occurred:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/<myName>/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/easy-install.pth'
```

and

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/<myName>/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg'
```

Now, when using `pip`, I get the error that there is `No module named 'pkg_resources'`.

I tried the solution in the thread [No module named pkg_resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources):

Using

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py | python
```

again produced the following error (also when using `sudo curl`):

```
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/<myName>/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/easy-install.pth'
```

Trying to reinstall `setuptools` as was also suggested:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

results in the same `No module named 'pkg_resources'` error message.

I am using MacOS 10.12.4

Comment: What are the file permissions of `/Users/<myName>/anaconda/lib/python3.5/` and `/Users/<myName>/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-å/` ?

Comment: I have got `drwx` right for the `.../python3.5/site-packages` folder but somehow the `easy-install.pth` is the only file in this folder where I just got `rw` permissions.

Comment: Try to execute `chmod +x easy-install.pth` to get exectuve permissions. It is normal that the the `d` permission is missing for the `.pth` file, as it is a file and not a directory.

Comment: I think that you might have run some `sudo` command in the past which mixed the owner of the file, too. Try to change the owner from `sudo` to your own user account and check if the error is solved.

Comment: That solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first: you should always watch out when you execute any command via `sudo` - this might really screw your file permissions up. As it seems, this is exactly what has happened here. Your user account has to take over the permissions of the `easy-install.pth`. Try to execute

```
sudo chown myuser easy-install.pth
chmod +x easy-install.pth
```

Then continue with the

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py | python
```

command to fix your `No module named 'pkg_resources'` problem. Now your `pip` should be working again.
Afterwards try to upgrade `tensorflow` again with `pip install tensorflow --upgrade` and check if this has solved your problem.