# error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/sunny/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/easy-install.pth'

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I want to install TensorFlow with Virtualenv, I meet a problem:

```
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

I want to fix this problem with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources).

But when I code like this

```
sudo curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py | python
```

I meet another problem:

```
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/sunny/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/easy-install.pth''
```

My system is Mac OS.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#installing_with_virtualenv

Comment: Your `sudo` is applying to `curl`, not `python`. Thus, the `python` invocation is running unprivileged.

Comment: **Normally**, that's fine: In general, you shouldn't use `sudo` at all when installing to a virtualenv inside your home directory -- not needing to escalate privileges is part of the point. However, since you used `sudo` for it once in the past, you now need to do so again going forward, until you `chown` all the relevant files back to yourself, rather than being owned by root (as running an install with `sudo` would have left them).

Comment: In the interim: `sudo chown -R sunny /Users/sunny/anaconda` will switch files under that directory back to be owned by yourself again. And don't use `sudo` again for installations into that location in the future.