# Creating a new Container with Azure-Cli

Tags: python, azure, azure-cli

I installed azure-cli with Homebrew `brew update && brew install azure-cli`

None of the azure commands have been successful. No matter the command I get the the following error.

```
az storage container create --name testContainer
No module named 'pkg_resources'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.45/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 197, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.45/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 262, in execute
    self.commands_loader.load_arguments(command)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.45/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 253, in load_arguments
    self.command_table[command].load_arguments()  # this loads the arguments via reflection
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.45/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 141, in load_arguments
    super(AzCliCommand, self).load_arguments()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.45/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/knack/commands.py", line 76, in load_arguments
    cmd_args = self.arguments_loader()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.45/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 440, in default_arguments_loader
    op = handler or self.get_op_handler(operation)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.45/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 485, in get_op_handler
    op = import_module(mod_to_import)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.45/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/multiapi/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

I've attempted to do `pip install setuptools`
which gives me:

```
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (40.4.1)
```

Is azure trying to use a different version of python that's missing setup tools? Am I using the wrong version of python?

I don't really know where to go from here.

`python --version` says i'm using Python 3.7.0

Comment: You should create an issue here and CLI team will help you to figure out what is happening: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues. Also, you don't confirm how you installed the CLI is the first place. Pip? Howebrew? Something else? Please update your post with installation details.

Comment: @LaurentMazuel, updated. I'll post in their issues as well.

Comment: A similar error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources

Comment: Your message show the CLI is in 3.7, and you pip try is in 2.7 (look at the path). Try "python -m pip install setuptools"

Comment: What the steps do you follow? This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest)?

Comment: I ended up running a Brew Uninstall of Azure-Cli and then doing a pip install of the same package and it worked ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: If the answer is helpful you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say none of the azure commands have been successful. So I suggest you reinstall the Azure CLI, you can follow [Install Azure CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).

Additional, install Azure CLI through python:

```
pip install --pre --user azure-nspkg 
pip install --pre --user azure-multiapi-storage
pip install azure-cli
```

For more details, follow this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/3264).

About create a container for the storage. You can do that with the CLI command here:

```
az storage container create --name containerName --account-name accountName --account-key accountKey
```

And the container name has the limitation here:

> A container organizes a set of blobs, similar to a folder in a file
>   system. All blobs reside within a container. A storage account can
>   contain an unlimited number of containers, and a container can store
>   an unlimited number of blobs. **Note that the container name must be
>   lowercase.**

So you should pay attention to it. Hope this will help you.

Comment: My solution was to reinstall the CLI using pip instead of brew. If you include `pip install azure-cli` in your answer I'll accept it.