# GNS3 Python error when installing gns3-gui on linux

Tags: python-3.x

Can you please help, getting below error installing gns3 2.1.10, running Debian with kernel 4.18, have munuallyinstalled python 3.5, not sure what is the problem.

Setting up gns3-server (2.1.10~xenial1) ...
cp: cannot stat '/usr/bin/python3.5': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/usr/bin/python3.5': No such file or directory
WARNING: Some error occured while updating /usr/share/gns3/gns3-server/bin/python3
Setting up gns3-gui (2.1.10~xenial1) ...
cp: cannot stat '/usr/bin/python3.5': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/usr/bin/python3.5': No such file or directory
WARNING: Some error occured while updating /usr/share/gns3/gns3-gui/bin/python3
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-6) ...

Thanks in-advance.

Comment: As the error states that python3.5 is not in the path `usr/bin/python3.5` and you've built Python from source then your python3.5 path could be `/usr/local/bin/python3.5`.

Comment: Thanks, moved python3.5 files from /usr/local/bin to usr/bin/, and it install's fine, getting this error message, when running from terminal. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gns3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources'

Comment: See if this question helps [No module named pkg_resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources). Also I think it would be a better idea to direct your gns installation to use Python 3.5 from `/usr/local/bin/` rather than moving the whole Python installation to some other path. I do not have much idea about what all could go wrong if you move your Python installation but I can certainly say that such a fix would definitely cause unwanted problems.

Answer (score 0):

#### Resolved Error Installing GNS3 for Linux

Hello M0rph3us ... This might help you.

```
$ sudo apt update
```

```
$ sudo apt install dirmngr
```

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F88F6D313016330404F710FC9A2FD067A2E3EF7B
```

```
$ echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gns3.list
```

```
$ sudo apt update
```

```
$ sudo apt install gns3-gui
```

Now press <kbd>y</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

When you see the following dialog message, select `"Ok"` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you want ordinary users to run GNS3, then select `"Yes"` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Otherwise select `"No"` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now select `"Ok"` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you want ordinary users to use Wireshark to capture network packets, select `"Yes"` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This is not what you want on a production environment, but it’s hassle free setup for testing as you won’t have to run Wireshark as root each time.

On a production environment, just select `"No"` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

GNS3 should be installed.

Now reboot your computer with the following command:

```
$ sudo reboot
```