# AWS Lambda (python2.7): Adding matplotlib as a layer

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, aws-lambda, amazon-linux

I am having trouble trying to add `matplotlib` as a [layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) to my Python 2.7 AWS Lambda function.

On the [Lambda execution environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html), I am trying to install the necessary libraries and create a layer as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path).

Things I've tried:

First, I `pip install`ed matplotlib into a virtual environment and copied the contents of the site-packages under lib and lib64. When the lambda function is executed, I get a `No module named pkg_resources` exception. I also tried installing with the `--target` option to install all dependancies to the same folder. The result was the same.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10538412/287923) that it may be due to outdated setuptools package. When I did an update `pip install --upgrade setuptools` and then tried to install matplotlib I started getting the following exception:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Finally I thought of installing matplotlib with

```
sudo yum install python-matplotlib
```

and then collect the required packages as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-linux-binary-package/). But this did not make matplotlib importable from within the python shell, so I guess it won't work as a Lambda layer.

Thanks for any help.

P.S: At AWS re:invent, exactly this was [demoed](https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/reinvent-deep-dive-on-lambda-layers-and-runtime-api) but there are no details on the session :/

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar issues with other modules such as crypto and my own custom modules.  I discovered the problem is really a lack of good documentation.

In my case, I was zipping all the dependencies up from the target directory, using the --target option, so all the dependency directories were at the top level of the zip file.  That works fine for straight Lambda deployment, but when you want to use a layer, the layer is deployed in to the /opt folder of your Lambda container, so you need to create your zip file with a top-level directory named 'python' so that your dependencies can be located at /opt/python/.

```
mkdir python && cd python && pip install pyopenssl crypto --target . && cd .. && zip -r9 ./lambda_layer.zip python/
```

It does appear in the documentation but it is brief and VERY easy to miss.  This page helped me: https://medium.com/@adhorn/getting-started-with-aws-lambda-layers-for-python-6e10b1f9a5d

Good luck!