# Google App Engine: ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to get region name from 2 letters state code for US. I am seeing mentioned import error on google app engine for code below.

```
import us
```

I am using python2.7 google app engine gcloud setup. Below is the command I used for deployment

```
gcloud app deploy
```

Comment: Have a look at this Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10538412/609290

Comment: @DazWilkin Hi, ya I already went over it. I can see inside google cloud sdk, pkg_resources is present. But after I deploy it could not find. Libraries are managed by google app engine itself. We have no control over it.

Comment: You're `pip install`'ing at least `us==1.0.0` before deployment, right?

Comment: Yes I had included latest us lib in GAE project

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Using `virtualenv`? Standard or Flexible? If I have time later today, I'll try to repro but I suspect it's something with your local config.

Comment: Thanks a lot. No not using virtualenv. I am using GAE standard env. As us lib is not supported by GAE standard env. I have included this to project repo. And then deployed using gcloud command

Comment: It works for me *iff* I vendor both `us` and `setuptools`. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library and `pip install -t lib/ us` and `pip install -t lib/ setuptools`

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks a lot. Ya if we include setuptools then it works. But not sure if its a good idea to include that in app engine project

Comment: If you pay for support, Consider contacting Google. Otherwise perhaps file an issue to gain some clarity: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues

Comment: It's OK to vendor `setuptools` into your project, but it is one of the [built-in third-party libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27), are you [specifying it in your `app.yaml` file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#using_a_built-in_third-party_library_bundled_with_the_runtime)?

Comment: Nope I did not specify it in app.yaml file before. I will specify that in app.yaml file. 
Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Setuptools is one of the [built-in third-party libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27). Per ["Using a built-in third-party library bundled with the runtime"](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#using_a_built-in_third-party_library_bundled_with_the_runtime), are you specifying `setuptools` in your `app.yaml` file?

```
libraries:
- name: setuptools
  version: "36.6.0"
```

Comment: Perhaps a typo, but that version didn't work (couldn't be uploaded) with `gcloud app deploy`, however it suggested `36.6.0` which did.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble! Yes that was a typo.