# xattr: ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Tags: python, macos, setuptools, pkg-resources, xattr

I was trying to run `xattr` on **macOS Catalina 10.15.2** and the error occurred:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/xattr", line 8, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

So I tried the solution given by [@cwc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10538412/10690911) and installed the latest version of `setuptools`

```sh
pip install -U setuptools

Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/general/lib/python3.7/site-packages (45.1.0)
```

I also installed `setuptools` using `pip3`

```sh
pip3 install -U setuptools

Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (45.1.0)
```

Besides, I tried the methods above in different `conda` environments with Python **3.6.10** and **3.7.4**, but the problem was not solved. Any ideas as to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xattr` as included in **Catalina** uses the system-installed *Python 2.7*. (As shown by the `head` command below.) So you need to make sure that version is set up correctly.

```
$ head /usr/bin/xattr
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

Make sure python is using the system default version:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Then, run the following commands

```
$ python -m ensurepip --default-pip
$ python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
$ python -m pip install --upgrade xattr==0.6.4
$ /usr/bin/xattr
```

Using `pip` in this way means that the the module is being run from `site-packages` directly, and will not clobber any other `pip` on your system (i.e. from Python 3.7)