# Error with SnowSQL installation in windows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried installing the SnowSQL from the installer as available from the web interface. The installer runs but when I try to run a command in command prompt it gives me the below error.

```
C:\Users\rahul.sharma>snowsql
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "c:\windows\temp\snowsql\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 86, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources.py2_warn'
[15764] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres
```

I have also tried uninstalling and re-installing, but still, it gives me the same error. Can someone assist with this?

Comment: Do you have this python module installed? pip install setuptools via: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with the Snowsql download from within the application (via the Help menu) so the workaround for now is to manually download the previous version directly from the repo:

For AWS Platform Account :

```
Download the Snowsql 1.2.1 for Linux:  
https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql/bootstrap/1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.1-linux_x86_64.bash
Download the Snowsql 1.2.1 for MacOS:  
https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql/bootstrap/1.2/darwin_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.1-darwin_x86_64.pkg
Download the Snowsql 1.2.1 for Windows:  
https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql/bootstrap/1.2/windows_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.1-windows_x86_64.msi
```

For Azure Platform Account:

```
Download the Snowsql 1.2.1 for Linux:  
https://sfc-repo.azure.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql/bootstrap/1.2/linux_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.2-linux_x86_64.bash
Download the Snowsql 1.2.1 for MacOS:  
https://sfc-repo.azure.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql/bootstrap/1.2/darwin_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.1-darwin_x86_64.pkg
Download the Snowsql 1.2.1 for Windows:  
https://sfc-repo.azure.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql/bootstrap/1.2/windows_x86_64/snowsql-1.2.1-windows_x86_64.msi
```