# No module named 'pkg_resources' when installing setuptools in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, pip, installation, package

In order to fix some problems, I uninstalled `setuptools` and tried to reinstall it. I successfully uninstalled it with

```
pip3 uninstall -y setuptools
```

But when I tried to reinstall it with

```
pip3 install setuptools
```

I got the error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

Now I searched for solution of this error, and the answer is that I got the message because I'm missing the `setuptools` package. So when trying to install the package `setuptools`, I got this error message, which tells me to install `setuptools` first... any idea how I can solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Did you take a look at the many answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources)?

Comment: I tried many of them, but whenever I tried to install python-pkg-resources or setuptools I get the same error message of No module named 'pkg_resources'

Comment: Can you share some information on your environment?