# Python Pip: No module named pkg_resources

Tags: python, macos, pip, installation

I am a bloody beginner with programming in general and am just getting started with python. I tried installing pygame (on Mac OS) with pip by using

```
§ pip install pygame
```

but got an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

So i tried (for some reason) installing pip again. with

```
§ sudo pip uninstall pip
§ sudo pip install pip
```

both resulting in the same error message as before. I uninstalled python to make sure I am on the newest version but if anything it's made things worse. Pretty much any command containing pip yields the same eroor message.
I have literlly zero experience working with the terminal window so if you know the answer, please dumb it down a little.

EDIT: Here is a list of commands that I tried, that give the same error message:

```
pip    
sudo pip
sudo pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

A list of commands I tried that result in other error messages:

```
sudo easy_install install setuptools --upgrade
```

results in

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 8, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named pkg\_resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources)

Comment: I don't think so. The solution they propose just results in another error message.

Answer (score 8):

This mostly should be the issue regarding the setuptools, as python requires OS and version specific setup tools.
You can try installing Setup tools using the following command.

```
pip install setuptools
```

You Can Also Try The Following:

```
sudo pip install setuptools --upgrade
or sudo easy_install install setuptools --upgrade
```

According to some similar posts on Internet this should work

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-pkg-resources
```

Comment: I just tried that and got the same error message from before

Comment: Which Os Are you Using? // Check my recent changes to the post if that helps

Comment: MacOS Catalina. First one results in the same error message. Second one results in a similar error message (see edited post). Do you think there ist a way to just reinstall the whole thing?

Comment: You can try reinstalling python maybe

Comment: How are you installing Python?  If you use Anaconda to install python, don't use pip!  Use conda instead.

Comment: For py3 crowd, `sudo apt install --reinstall python3-pkg-resources python3-setuptools`