# Error: No module named pkg_resources. How do I install?

Tags: python, terminal, pip

So I did a huge mistake. I was trying to install python latest version so I went to finder and deleted all data related to my previous version of python some 4000 plus files. now when I type `python --version` on terminal it still shows the old one. and when I try to install pip it shows :

> File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 8, in 
> from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
>
> ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Can anyone please help

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the old version and then uninstall it.