# Have difficulty to solve "No module named pkg_resources"

Tags: python

Hope someone can help me! I appreciate it.

I tried to download some open source from GitHub, but it shows "No module named pkg_resources".
Then I searched some solution from [No module named pkg_resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources) , but it showed the error below. I also found some solution from other articles, but it still not working.

```
Installing Setuptools
running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/test-easy-install-48274.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Something went wrong during the installation.
See the error message above.
```

p.s. I couldn't open that link in the error messages https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html.

By the way, I've checked my pip version and it also showed "No module named pkg_resources". I'm confused because I use Python for like 1-2 years, and everything goes fine, but I just found this error message today. If I couldn't solve this problem, it might be a huge trouble because I can't download everything about "Pip".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution would be to download [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), then run it using `sudo`:

```bash
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

assuming you have admin permissions on your computer. `easy_install` has been deprecated for a long time, and `pip` is definitely the way to go. By reinstalling `pip`, `setuptools` and all its dependencies should be correctly installed as well.

Comment: Great! It works for me though I got another error while downloading that open source.  By the way, do I need to install easy_install?

Comment: No, you don't need `easy_install`. `pip` handles pretty much everything nowadays.